# Proper way to implement (Mnesia-style / wildcard / don't care) tuple matching (Erlang)

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I'm implementing a Chess game (Chinese Chess, aka. Xiangqi, to be exact) in Erlang.

A piece is represented by a `{Color, Type}` tuple, and a point (ie. location) is represented by a `{File, Rank}` tuple. The board is represented by a point-to-piece map (ie. `#{point() => piece()}`).

There is a function to query whether a particular point on the board is occupied by a piece or not:

```
is_point_occupied_simple(Board, Point) ->
    ensure_is_point(Point),
    case maps:find(Point, Board) of
        {ok, _} ->
            true;
        error ->
            false
    end.
```

However, I would like to add an optional parameter to check the color of the piece - if the point is occupied by a piece of the specified color, the function returns true; otherwise it returns false. If I don't care about the color of the piece, I can just put `'_'` in the `TargetColor` parameter (or, equivalently, invoke `is_point_occupied/2`):

```
is_point_occupied(Board, Point) ->
    is_point_occupied(Board, Point, '_').

is_point_occupied(Board, Point, '_') ->
    ensure_is_point(Point),
    case maps:find(Point, Board) of
        {ok, _} ->
            true;
        error ->
            false
    end;

is_point_occupied(Board, Point, TargetColor) ->
    ensure_is_point(Point),
    ensure_is_color(TargetColor),
    case maps:find(Point, Board) of
        {ok, {TargetColor, _}} ->
            true;
        {ok, _} ->
            false;
        error ->
            false
    end.
```

I don't like the above implementation because of the large proportion of copy-and-paste, so I simplified the above function like this:

```
is_point_occupied_2(Board, Point) ->
    is_point_occupied_2(Board, Point, '_').

is_point_occupied_2(Board, Point, TargetColor) ->
    ensure_is_point(Point),
    ensure_is_color_or_wildcard(TargetColor),
    case maps:find(Point, Board) of
        {ok, {TargetColor, _}} ->
            true;
        {ok, _} ->
            is_wildcard(TargetColor);
        error ->
            false
    end.
```

The function `is_wildcard/1` is simply a one-liner:

```
is_wildcard(Wildcard) -> Wildcard =:= '_'.
```

Now, I would like to go further to replace `TargetColor` by `TargetPiece`, which is a `{TargetColor, TargetType}` tuple. None, one or both of the tuple elements may be a wildcard (`'_'`). I found it difficult to write the `case` clauses. I also notice that to match an n-tuple allowing "don't care" in this way, there needs 2<sup>n</sup> clauses. So obviously it is not the proper way to implement this.

Does anyone have better ideas?

PS: I didn't include the source of all functions since those I didn't include are trivial to implement in my opinion. Please leave a comment below if you're interested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this is to implement an auxiliary function for matching, which makes the 2<sup>n</sup> `case` clauses mentioned above into n `orelse` clauses plus n-1 `andalso` clauses:

```
match_piece({Color, Type} = Piece, {TargetColor, TargetType} = TargetPiece) ->
    ensure_is_piece(Piece),
    ensure_is_piece_or_wildcard(TargetPiece),
    (is_wildcard(TargetColor) orelse Color =:= TargetColor)
        andalso (is_wildcard(TargetType) orelse Type =:= TargetType).
```

The main function doesn't change much:

```
is_point_occupied_3(Board, Point) ->
    is_point_occupied_3(Board, Point, {'_', '_'}).

is_point_occupied_3(Board, Point, TargetPiece) ->
    ensure_is_point(Point),
    ensure_is_piece_or_wildcard(TargetPiece),
    case maps:find(Point, Board) of
        {ok, Piece} ->
            match_piece(Piece, TargetPiece);
        error ->
            false
    end.
```

Is there any better / alternative ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the chess board representation, filling the whole board by either a piece {Color,Type} or no piece {none,none} so your code can be more regular:

```
-module (testmatch).

-compile([export_all]).

is_point_occupied(Board,Point) -> not match(maps:find(Point, Board),{none,none}).
is_point_occupied(Board,Point,Color) -> match(maps:find(Point, Board),{Color,'_'}).
is_point_occupied(Board,Point,Color,Type) -> match(maps:find(Point, Board),{Color,Type}).

match({ok,{C,T}},{C,T}) -> true;
match({ok,{_C,T}},{'_',T}) -> true;
match({ok,{C,_T}},{C,'_'}) -> true;
match(_,_) -> false.

test() ->
    Board = #{1 =>{none,none}, 2 =>{black,king}, 3 => {white,tower} },
    false = is_point_occupied(Board,1),
    true = is_point_occupied(Board,2),
    false = is_point_occupied(Board,2,red),
    true = is_point_occupied(Board,2,black),
    false = is_point_occupied(Board,3,'_',king),
    true = is_point_occupied(Board,3,'_',tower),
    true = is_point_occupied(Board,2,black,king),
    false = is_point_occupied(Board,2,black,tower),
    false = is_point_occupied(Board,2,white,king).
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, does it mean your board needs 8 x 8 = 64 elements for Chess (and 9 x 10 = 90 elements for Chinese Chess)? Since memory consumption is important here, I think it may not be a good approach. Furthermore, to match an n-tuple {E1, E2, ..., En}, 2^n match/2 clauses must be written. As I mentioned, I doubt whether it is the proper way to do it. By the way, Chess is used here only as an example, my main focus is on the "don't care"-style matching. Is it a must to change the board definition? Is there a more elegant solution than mine to achieve this? Thanks!